# Looking for REST API to list all Containers of Azure Data Lake Gen2 Storage

Tags: java, azure, api, rest, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to get all available Container Names from a specified Azure Data Lake Gen2 Storage as the image below.

[image]

I found these two posts from MS documentation, but it does not satisfy my requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/filesystem/list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list

Is there REST APIs that I can get all available Container Names from a specified Azure DL2 Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Data Lake Gen 2 accounts are built on top of Blob Storage, you can use Blob Storage REST API to perform most of the operations.

To list containers, you would use **List Containers REST API**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2?tabs=azure-ad.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav. I can retrieve the containers now.